# image not correctly resized in chrome, compared to Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, firefox

I have an html page displaying an image.
When the image is larger than the window of the browser, the image is resized (keeping the same ratio) to fit in the window with Firefox.
But with Chrome, the image is compressed

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="auto">
    <img class="full-width" src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/img-1.jpg" />
    <div class="absolute">
        <img src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/left.png" alt="#" class="left">
        <img src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/right.png" alt="#" class="right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.auto {
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
    }

    .absolute {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        z-index:2;
    }

    .left {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:15px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .right {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        right:15px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

  .full-width {
    width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    height:100%;
  }
```

How can I change the code so that it works (resize) both on Firefox and Chrome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used js to set the correct size of the div according to the size of the image.

html:

```
<div class='fill-screen'>
<img id="photo" class='make-it-fit' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa.jpg'>
<div id="over_image">
  <div class="left">
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)#/media/File:U%2B2190.svg" style="outline:0">
      <img src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/left.png" alt="#">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)#/media/File:U%2B2192.svg">
      <img src="http://laurent.delrocq.free.fr/test/right.png" alt="#">
    </a>
  </div></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.fill-screen {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
img.make-it-fit {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#over_image {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;

    height:100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}



.left{
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
}

.left a, .right a{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.right{
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 80%;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
}

.left:hover{
  opacity:1;
}

.right:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

js:

```
function resizeDiv()
{
  var img = document.getElementById('photo'); 

  var width  = img.clientWidth;
  var height = img.clientHeight;
  var left   = img.offsetLeft;
  var top    = img.offsetTop;

  document.getElementById('over_image').style.width= width + 'px';
  document.getElementById('over_image').style.height= height + 'px';
  document.getElementById('over_image').style.top= top + 'px';
  document.getElementById('over_image').style.left= left + 'px';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeDiv();
})

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeDiv();
})
```

The corresponding jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/4kxjt813/

Answer (score 0):

Mate, here is solution you search for:
https://jsfiddle.net/d5z3fnjh/1/

Check '.container', '.auto' and '.full-width' width and height values:

```
.full-width {
  width:100%;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
}
.auto {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

UPD:
Here is a solution with JS:
https://jsfiddle.net/d5z3fnjh/4/

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. It works the same way on both Firefox and Chrome. Unfortunately, it removes the behavior I put in place so that the image is always fully contained in the window  : a scrollbar is added when the height of the window is too small.  So i am still looking for a solution...

Comment: Added max-heigth and overflow:hidden. Sorry, can't edit previous comment.

Comment: There is no more scrollbar, but the image is truncated when you change the window height. So this is still not the solution I am looking for...

Comment: If you can use JS - this may be solution you search for (need to check it in browser): https://jsfiddle.net/d5z3fnjh/4/

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using js. I will think about what I can do. Note: the provided jsfiddle does not provide the required behavior : the arrows go outside of the image if the window is too large + the rules in the js shall not be about the width/height  ratio of the window but about the image.